# Is there a way to connect to Highspot APIs using nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to connect to Highspot APIs using nodejs?

I did not see a straigh forward way to extract data from HighSpot using their APIs.

From what I understand, we need to use connect to other systems like Salesforce or Google etc to be able to extract data.

Sample code I used for testing:

```
const highspotAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.highspot.com/v1", // Assuming this is the base URL for the API
});

async function login(clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://api.highspot.com/v1/oauth/token",
      {
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
      }
    );

    // Assuming successful response returns an access token
    const accessToken = response.data.access_token;

    // Set access token in request headers for highspotAPI
    highspotAPI.defaults.headers.common[
      "Authorization"
    ] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

    return accessToken;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(
      "Error logging in:",
      error.response ? error.response.data : error.message
    );
    throw error;
  }
}

// Example function to retrieve content
async function getContent() {
  try {
    const response = await highspotAPI.get("/content");
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching content:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

// Usage
(async () => {
  try {
    // Replace these with your actual credentials and refresh token
    const clientId = "your_client_id";
    const clientSecret = "your_client_secret";
    const refreshToken = "your_refresh_token";

    const token = await login(clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken);
    console.log("Access Token:", token);

    // Now you can use getContent() and createContent() functions
    // const content = await getContent();
    // console.log("Content:", content);

    // const newContent = await createContent({
    //   /* Content data */
    // });
    // console.log("New Content:", newContent);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: This is something you’d generally consult with the vendor on if they haven’t provided any documentation or SDKs to do so. However speaking specifically to *feasibility*, there is at least one unofficial SDK for Python available which would generally indicate there is a possibility to do this in another language like Node.js.

Comment: @esqew -- Yes thats right, I did find a github repo (https://github.com/jeffshurtliff/highspot/tree/master).

Comment: So, that should answer your question. Does it? Separately - from where did you get the code you’ve edited into your question? What’s wrong with it exactly? It looks like it was generated by GPT - if so, are you aware of [SO’s current policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)?

Comment: The code doesn’t work, apparently the APIs don't exist. I will have a look at the link, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.